# Is django thread blocked while sending email?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, email, celery

I have a django-rest-framework API, and am trying to understand how sending email from it works. Suppose I'm using django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend as email backend to send emails. Sending of an email is quite slow, and I'm wondering, if the django main thread will be blocked somehow during that time so that the other APIs would be unusable during it? Is that true? Would it be a good call to send the email in a background process created by celery for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Django thread is blocked for that particular user. You might want to use Celery along with Rabbit Mq for sending mail in background.

Comment: The same user could not send other requests during that time? Or is the benefit that I could return response of the mail to front before the mail is sent, so the front can continue without waiting the response?

Comment: What happens is the front end freezes or blocks till the time the mail is not sent. So basically what you do with celery and rabbit mq is create a very quick task in the back-end. This task is then executed later when there is free time available or a predetermined time in a non-blocking way. I dont know if you can directly send a response back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the thread handling the request will be blocked until the email is sent. In a typical Django setup one thread is created per request.

Comment: One thread per request? Does this mean, that other requests from the same user would work fine during that time?

Comment: Yes, that means that other requests, even from the same user, can be handled simultaneously, up to the maximum number of threads. However, you still have a blocking thread, and it will limit the concurrency you can achieve.

Comment: This isn't true. Django doesn't spin up threads per request at all. Thread handling is left to the server itself, which may or may not be configured to use threads, but in any case threads are not created or destroyed per request.

Comment: By `in a typical Django setup` I meant using `gunicorn`.